# Nested form in separate blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a parent and child object, parents can accept_nested_attributes_for :child, and a nested form:

```
form_for :parent do |f|

  f.text_input :parent_field1
  f.text_input :parent_field2
  f.text_input :parent_field3

  f.fields_for :child do |f|

    f.text_input :child_field1
    f.text_input :child_field2
    f.text_input :child_field3
  end
end
```

A child object is created when the parent is created. I am wondering if there is any way to alternate parent and child fields and maintain the same functionality? I have tried the following, but it instantiates three different child objects instead of one:

```
form_for :parent do |f|

  f.text_input :parent_field1

  f.fields_for :child do |f|
    f.text_input :child_field1
  end

  f.text_input :parent_field2

  f.fields_for :child do |f|
    f.text_input :child_field2
  end

  f.text_input :parent_field3

  f.fields_for :child do |f|
    f.text_input :child_field1
  end
end
```

I have also tried adding an instance variable but that instantiated multiple objects as well.

```
Controller

def new
   @parent = Parent.new
   @child = @parent.child.new
end

Form

f.fields_for @child do |f|
  f.text_input :child_field1
end
```

Any idea how to spread fields_for into independent blocks of code (and reference the same object) instead of a single block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place parent inputs inside fileds_for block as well, you only need to remember to use parent form_builder:

```
form_for :parent do |f|
  f.fields_for :child |ff|
    f.text_input :parent_field1
    ff.text_input :child_field1
    f.text_input :parent_field2
    ff.text_input :child_field2
    f.text_input :parent_field3
    ff.text_input :child_field1
  end
end
```

If for some reason the parent form_builder is outside of current scope (i.e. you can't use `f` - it might happen if you are building nested fields with partials), you can always get the parent form_builder using:

```
ff.parent_builder.text_field :parent_field
```

However this should be used in rather rare cases.

Comment: I think this (form_for) is an example of rails convention breaking good programming conventions, ie not being declarative. We're usually told not to call variables things like "f", and i've seen other cases where people don't realise that "f" is just a regular variable here rather than something more magical.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Good point. However I wouldn't try to change this convention more than rather use different letters than `f`. it can be `c` for child, `p` for parent - but definitively nothing longer. Tried it once it made view reading a nightmare since it is literally repeated everywhere.

Comment: Yeah - it's such a convention that it's kind of embedded in the "rails consciousness" now.  :)